# Cowfiles directory?

Tags: bash, directory-structure, cowsay

My bashrc issues a cow from `cowsay` and with a random `fortune`.

Like this:

```
echo -e "\e[00;33m $(fortune -a -o -s | cowsay -f $(ls /usr/share/cowsay/cows/ | shuf -n1) | sed -e 's/^/       /g')\e[00m"
```

This works on Linux Mint but I moved to Arch Linux, and the cowfile directory is different now.

Is there a standard way to figure out the cow directory?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`cowsay -l` lists all avaliable cowfiles.

```
cowsay -l | tail -n +2 | tr ' ' '\n' | shuf -n 1
```

`tail -n +2` removes the first line, which states the path to Cow files that will be used ("Cow files in /usr/share/cows:" in cowsay 3.02-8 in Arch linux), `tr ' ' '\n'` separates the output into lines and, finally, `shuf -n 1` chooses a random cow.

Comment: Remember to mark your answer as 'accepted', so everyone knows that you have solved your problem.

Comment: I can't in the first two days...

Comment: Of course, I forgot that! My apologies.